# Configure VM on Windows 10 with VirtualBox similar to Docker Quick Start Terminal

Tags: bash, virtualbox

Docker Toolbox for Windows uses `boot2docker.iso` for creating Linux VM and puts Docker Quick Start Terminal shortcut which when started opens bash shell to home directory on Windows.

When executing `cd ~` it actually opens `c:\Users\%USERNAME%`.

And `whoami` reports `%USERNAME%`.

Could I configure another guest Linux VM to start like this?

Comment: Today I watch MS announcement from Build 2016 conference about Ubuntu in Windows 10 which sounds quite the same as what I outline above but without VM.